# How can I make a credit page like the credit page of "angry bird"?

Tags: android

I want to make a credit page.

Therefore, a automatically rolling page is needed.

I had tried the method of animation.

```
TranslateAnimation am = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, 0, -(1884+342));
am.setDuration(30000);
am.setRepeatMode(Animation.RESTART);    
am.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
containView.setAnimation(am);
```

However, the view can not be rolling by finger event if I register the onClick event.

Does it any way to make a credit page like angry birds?

Answer (score 0):

What exactly is your problem ?

did you try doing something like

1) register anmation on your panel

2) register listener that stops the animation on click to allow the default behavior to run normally

3) on finger up you start an new animation form the ne point our at

Comment: Do you mean this kind of solution?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5828423/android-animation-pause-and-play-problem

Comment: Wrong type at the enter.
Actually, I have no idea about how to make the view rolling infinity.